# Allow only certain people to post on my Facebook Timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

Is it possible to allow only certain people or groups to post on my timeline?

Or alternatively - can I disallow certain people or groups (like Acquaintances) to post on my timeline, but without the need of un-frieniding or blocking them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Facebook settings allow only one of two options:

- you can either let all of your friends (including acquaintances) post on your timeline,
- or no one but you would be able to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can allow only a subset of friends to see what others post on your timeline.  Anyone who is not permitted to see what others post on your timeline cannot post on your timeline either.